# Нарушено ограничение уникальности

Tags: sql, plsql, plsql-developer

Банальный запрос

```
insert into metrology.attr(id, name, custom_script, dic_type, dic_id, visible_style)
values(236, 'Дискретность отсчета', '', '', '', 0)
```

выдает ora-00001 "нарушено ограничение уникальности (metrology.pk_attr)"
При этом при попытке обратиться к таблице metrology.pk_attr выводится сообщение что таблицы не существует. Как разрешить проблему? Благодарен заранее.

Comment: Да, так оно и есть. Спасибо, вопрос решен!

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle в сообщениях об ошибках указывает имена объектов, которые эту ошибку обнаружили. Эти объекты чаще всего не таблицы. В сообщениях о нарушении уникальности указывается имя первичного ключа или уникального индекса обнаружившего дублирование информации.

В вашем случае `pk_attr` это (судя по названию) первичный ключ таблицы `attr` и скорее всего этот ключ сделан по полю `id` таблицы. Значит в таблице `attr` уже есть запись с id=236 и добавление еще одной такой же приводи к ошибке нарушения уникальности (ORA-00001)